# Show that measure is symmetric iff characteristic function real-valued

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, trigonometry, exponential-function

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space $E$ and $$\mu^-(B):=\mu(-B)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(E).$$ Remember that $\mu$ is called *symmetric* if $\mu=\mu^-$.

> How can we show that
>
> 1. $\mu$ is symmetric;
> 2. the characteristic function $\varphi_\mu$ of $\mu$ is real-valued;
> 3. for all $x'\in E'$, $$\varphi_\mu(x')=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\cos\langle x,x'\rangle\tag1$$
>
> are equivalent?

The only trivial implication is "(3.) $\Rightarrow$ (2.)".

In order to show "(1.) $\Rightarrow$ (2.)", we clearly want to use that $$\varphi_\mu(x')=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}=\int\cos\langle x,x'\rangle+{\rm i}\sin\langle x,x'\rangle\mu({\rm d}x)\tag2$$ and $$\varphi_{\mu^-}(x')=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{-{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}=\int\cos\langle x,x'\rangle-{\rm i}\sin\langle x,x'\rangle\mu({\rm d}x)\tag3$$ for all $x'\in E'$.

Comment: Well, (1)→(2) follows directly from $\sin(-t)=-\sin(t)$. So if $\mu$ is symmetric the imaginary part will cancel out. For (2)→(1) simply argue that the characteristics of $\mu$ and $\mu^-$ are the same, so $\mu=\mu^-$.

Comment: $\widehat{\mu}(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $\overline{\widehat{\mu}}=\widehat{\mu}$, that is $\int e^{-ixt}\mu(dx)=\int e^{ixt}\,d\mu$. The measure $\mu^*(A)=\mu(-A)$ has characteristic function given by $\int e^{itx}\,d\mu$ (this is simple exercise). The uniques of the characteristic function implies that $\mu=\mu^*$ iff $\widehat{\mu}=\overline{\widehat{\mu}}$.

Comment: Also if $\mu=\mu^-$ then the characteristics are the same. Using your forms you can take the sum to get (1)→(3).

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your comment. Please note that we need to assume that $\mu$ is Radon in order to conclude $\mu=\mu^-$ from $\hat\mu=\hat{\mu^-}$. So, do we need this assumption or is there another argument?

Comment: @Lazy Please take note of my comment above.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Note that $\mu$ is not only locally finite, but even globally finite. Also note that any finite Borel measure is always regular. So in fact $\mu$ *is* radon.

Comment: @Lazy Unless the notion of "Borel measure" you've got in mind involves a certain regularity assumption on $\mu$, this is not true. If $\mu$ is an arbitrary finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a metric space $E$, it is only already Radon if $E$ is Polish (i.e. comlete and separable).

Comment: Of course the measures are Radon, finite Borel measures are Radon!

Comment: @OliverDiaz No, as I wrote before, whether this is true or not depends on what you mean by a "Borel" measure. Some authors simply mean *any* measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the given topological space; other authors include a regularity assumption. What I mean in the question is the former and hence - unless we explicitly assume this - $\mu$ not Radon in general. (Unless $E$ is separable and complete, in which case we can show it is Radon).

Comment: @OliverDiaz What we can show in general is that if $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on a metric space $E$, then it is "regular" in the sense that for every $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then $|\mu|(C\setminus A)<\varepsilon$ for some closed $A$ and open $C$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. If the metric space is complete and separable, then $\mu$ is radon.

Comment: There is not need of so much abstract nonsense. A finite measure $\mu$  is given (presumably on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, otherwise there's no point to discuss the Fourier transform). Without much fanfare one shows that if $\mu^*(A):=\mu(-A)$ then $\int f(x)\,\mu^*(dx)=\int f(-x)\,\mu(dx)$; hence $\widehat{\mu^*}=\overline{\widehat{\mu}}$.  Thus $\widehat{\mu}$ is real iff $\overline{\widehat{\mu}}=\widehat{\mu}$.  By uniqueness of the Fourier transform (some separability assumptions may be required in  general setting of Banach spaces) all this happens  iff $\mu=\mu^*$.  No more and no less

Comment: As for Radon measure, right, if the space is a separable and complete, then any finite Borel measure is a Radon measure. This is a result bu Ulam.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Well, didn't you admitted yourself that the "abstract nonsense" is not so nonsensical? The "uniqueness of the Fourier transform" doesn't hold on an arbitrary normed space $E$. This uniqueness results boils down to the fact that $\{e^{{\rm i}\varphi}:\varphi\in E'\}$ is a separating family for the set of finite (signed) *Radon* measures on $\mathcal B(E)$. You most probably think of $E=\mathbb R^d$, where - as discussed above - every finite (signed) measure is Radon.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: hence my comment on separability. The applications I have seen are related to Malliavin Calculus. If you have a specific application that requires you to work on Banach spaces with no separability, just spell it out. Generalizations for sake of generalizations is a fruitless exercise. You may post your question in MO and get probably more nuanced responses.